# GRant Access to write and read from a Folder to ASp.net application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

I need to allow my asp.net application to read and write from and to a folder. 
Could you please help me to do so.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your application pool is using the default identity (it probably is), then right click on the folder, select Properties, go to the Security tab, click Edit..., click Add..., in the object names field enter NETWORK SERVICE (also assuming IIS 6 or 7 here), click OK, in the permissions pane check Write, and click Apply.

That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

It's two pronged, neither of which involves your code, and both assume you have access to server settings. You need to have appropriate permissions set on the folder in the file system as well as within the IIS web application.